# How to pass data from jade to mongodb using NodeJS as the server language

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

I'm using NodeJS, Express, MongoDB, Mongoose and jade for the web app.
I am wondering how I pass data from jade to mongodb. The data that I want to pass are texts inside certain divs that are appended to the web page as users create them.

Example.

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    Object 1
  </div>

  <div class="c2">
    Object 2
  </div
</div>
```

I want to pass the text inside class c2 divs to mongodb. As of right now, I'm using

```
a(href="/save/", value="Publish", class="button") Publish
```

But the problem is that after if I press this link, it will get redirected to localhost:3000/save/ but all the populated divs will not get transported, as they shouldn't because I'm not passing anything. I'm thinking I should have some sort of onclick function for the link. But then I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do your users edit the texts inside the `div`s? Are you using `contentEditable`? While that's a nice feature, it requires some work and knowledge of web development to implement that properly.

I'd suggest the simplest and "proper" way to do it, would be use `textarea`s instead of the `div`s, and just submit them as a form:

```
<form action="/save/" method="post" class="c1">
  <textarea name="c2" class="c2">
    Object 1
  </textarea>

  <textarea name="c2" class="c2">
    Object 2
  </textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

Comment: The user submits a form entry and then the text that user inputted gets appended to a parent div, the class c1. I then wanted the text inside those c2 divs to get sent to the server. But, I will try your way, it seems really clever and don't see no reason why it shouldn't work. Otherwise I think I would have to do an ajax request or something I suppose.